# Require 'this' keyword in VS2022 while formatting and compiling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-formatting

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.4) and see that the formatting options have changed significantly.

I have tried experimenting and searching but cannot figure out how to force the required use of the `this` keyword when referring to instance fields, properties, methods, etc.

Setting VS `options` as well as editing the `*.editconfig` file has had no effect. The `this` keyword keeps getting removed during file saving, formatting, and compilation.

Comment: AFAIK there is no functionality in VS2022 out-of-the-box that automatically applies some code standard when formatting or saving a file. So probably you have some extension installed that does this job (e.g. ReSharper, CodeMaid, etc.) and this must be configured.

Comment: Why require `this` instead of using a naming convention that doesn't depend on it? `this.` isn't a "best practice" by any measure and can easily cause mixups. It exists mainly as a remnant of the VB6 to VB.NET transition, because VB6 didn't allow identifiers that started with `_`. In most other languages, `_` is used for field names, camel-case for parameters and variables, Pascal-case for public members. In the .NET Github repos you'll see both conventions - both `this.` and `_`.

Comment: Formatters and analyzers like Resharper and several Roslyn analyzers can enforce various naming conventions and some can even format a document automatically while saving. In fact `The this keyword keeps getting removed` that's probably an analyzer formatting on save

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I hadn't thought of that. It probably is an analyzer that is overwriting VS settings.